# will realtime data always show in reports?

Tags: google-analytics

I have implemented email tracking with help of google-alalytics following this [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/email). So far I am able to see the data in real time data under events (with event action = "open" and my desired event label). But even after 72 hrs, there is no data under Behavior->Events->Top events.

My question is: *Does real time data always reflect under Behavior->Events->Top events? Is it possible that the real time data just shows in real-time section and never makes it to the report in Behavior tab?*

Answer (score 0):

Real Time contains various metrics and dimensions that are widely spread like

- Page
- Events
- Sources etc

They can be seen in various reports across GA.

---

**Data Freshness**:

If you see your data in real time, and the changes you made is live to users, be assured they will be populated in GA. The time for data freshness in Free GA is 24+ hrs (GA360 is < 4hrs), so you can't say when they will be populated.

---

***Is it possible that the real-time data just shows in real-time section and never makes it to the report in Behavior tab?***

If you're seeing the events on real-time, they should go into your reports, or you wouldn't see them at all. Have you check if you have the current day selected on your calendar? By default, Analytics does not select current day, which may trick you.

Also, check if you don't have any filters applied of any kind that may change what you're seeing. One important thing is that analytics can take up to 48h - 72h to receive full information, so within that time frame, you may still not fully see the data on your reports.

It may take up to 5 days as well. I have seen cases like that. So be assured the data will be populated.

Comment: The first time, I was tricked by the current date not selected by default, but I do select current date when I check in the reports. Moreover the events I am tracking are happening everyday, so they should get detected at least for the previous day. Yes, there is one filter applied which excludes data from a particular IP address.